# Storing POSTdata in log in Salesforce

Tags: apex, logging

I have a custom VF page which receives POST from an external source and there's apex code to process that data. But before processing, I want to temporarily store the POST in Salesforce. I will delete the log entry if processing is completed successfully but in case it fails, we won't loose the POST data as it will still be stored in the log. I am not sure what is the best way/place to maintain this kind of log, does anyone have any suggestions/recommendations?

Comment: Is the processing all done in a single transaction? If so, there is no need to insert and the delete the POST data. Just create the custom record in the event of a processing problem. Remember, the DML actions won't be stored in the database until the transaction completes successfully.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO log is not a right place to store the raw POST data. Because of the following reasons:

- You cannot retrieve the exact request by request data
- There is a limit of 2MB on the logging data (Depends upon how big your POST data can be, so just keep this in mind)
- It is meant only for debugging and not for data storage

**Custom Object Approach**

I would rather suggest to create a intermediate object which will just contain the dump of the POST.

- **Object**: IntermediateCustomObject
- **Field:** PostDataField (Text Area Long)

> Text Area Long: Allows users to enter up to 131,072 characters on separate lines.

**Before Processing**

```
IntermediateCustomObject__c ico = new IntermediateCustomObject__c();
ico.PostDataField__c = Request.rawData;
insert ico;
```

**After Processing**

I am not sure what you are doing in the processing part and how complex it is. So after your processing is done delete the intermediate object.

```
delete ico;
```

Comment: Thanks KarthikSelva, that was really helpful. I created a custom object with post data and date stamp fields. I am adding a new record only when my process fails.